# TDBLookupCombobox FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, livebindings

### TDBLookupCombobox

Can anyone help me to reproduce **TDBLookupCombobox** functionality in FireMonkey?

Comment: All that i can achieve by myself it's:  
 1. Filling ComboBox
 2. BindPosition with its DataSet cursor
 3. It writes Primary Key of its DataSet instead of text equivalent.
But i cant figure out how to bind position of Combobox (or its DataSet) with value stored in DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better solution but this is what i do:

Suppose you have Table1 with a Foreign Key to Table2.

- Make a Lookup field in Table1 using the Foreign Key.
- Use TBindList to fill the `Text` property of the Combobox with the
  looked up field in Table2 and fill the `Tag` property with the
  Primary Key of Table2.
- Use TBindPosition to match the selected text with the
  lookup field and `Selected.Tag` with the Foreign Key in Table1.

edit:

Check the SourceComponent property of your TBindList and TBindPosition.

TBindList should point to the BindScopeDB of Table2.

TBindPosition, instead, to the BindScopeDB of Table1.

ControlComponent should point to your TComboBox for both.

When you use TBindList, `Format` collection expressions refer to the single item inside the ComboBox because it cycles for every row in your Table2 to fill the control. So ControlExpressions are the properties of each item:

`Text`,
`Tag`

Note: you don't need `Selected`

and these SourceExpressions:

`FieldByName(LookedUpField).AsString`,
`FieldByName(PK).AsInteger`

Put these expressions in the `Format` collection.

TBindPosition, instead, refers always to the whole ComboBox so you need to use `Selected`.
ControlExpressions:

`Selected.Tag`
`SelectedText(Self)`,

SourceExpressions:

`FieldByName(FK).AsInteger`,
`FieldByName(LookupField).AsString`

Remember that `PosSource` collection is used to set "ControlExpressions TO SourceExpressions" assignments while `PosControl` contains "SourceExpressions TO ControlExpressions" assignments.

Basically you need two things: change your selected item when Table1 cursor changes and set your FK using the Tag property of the selected item when user changes it.

So just put these in your PosControl collection:

`SelectedText(Self)` ControlExpression

`FieldByName(LookupField).AsString` SourceExpression

and these in your PosSource collection:

`Selected.Tag` ControlExpression

`FieldByName(FK).AsInteger` SourceExpression

If you want to make a similar behavior of TDBLookupComboBox you have to put the Table in Edit state when the selected combobox item is changed.

When I tried Firemonkey some months ago I needed more expressions to update the same field shown in a StringGrid but I don't know if there is a better solution for that. Hope someone else can answer and share his experience about this.

For more informations look for the examples included with XE2.

Hope this helped a bit.

Comment: I stuck at the same place, cant extract the Foreign Key from Table1. `Selected.Tag` binding seems not working. I have tried to do `Combobox1.Selected.Tag:=37;` and, obviously, its doesnt work. I think TBindPosition is the do the same thing, doesnt it? Xenon, pls, can you provide some source where it have been implemented? Or where i am wrong?

Comment: We need to bind Table1 value to `Dataset.Locate('id', *table1 value here*, []);`, but i dont know is livebindigs can do it?